# vertx 3 avoid nested Handler<AsyncResult> when doing a chain of vertex.fileSytem operations

Tags: asynchronous, functional-programming, java-8, filesystems, vert.x

In vertx 3 I want to do several `vertx.fileSystem()` operations,
where each one depends on the success of the previous one.

How can I avoid ending  up with nested  `Handler<AsyncResult>`

```
this.vertx.fileSystem().mkdir("my-temp", res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                this.vertx.fileSystem().move("/tmp/file.txt", "my-temp/file.txt", res2 -> {
                    if (res2.succeeded()) {
                        // having maybe even more nested Handler<AsyncResult>
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either use [Sequential composition](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_sequential_composition) or the [Vert.x API for RxJava](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java/)